# Apple : how to distribute without store?

Tags: ios, distribution

I am currently developing iPhone app, and I use a "Apple standard program".

At the moment, I am deploying this app to users with OTA with distribution certificat and OTA (over the air) installation.

It's working but i'm limited up to 100 devices.

I read that the "Apple Enterprise Program" don't have this limit (of 100 devices).

Is it right ?

If I enroll to Enterprise program, will I need to get UUID devices in order to generate provisioning profiles to deploy my app (like I do now with standard program and my 100 devices users) ?

Thanks for feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to know the UDIDs for Enterprise distributed apps.

It's very important to note however that you're not allowed to distribute Enterprise Apps to People other than your employees or other members of the organization which enrolled in the Enterprise Dev Program.

You should be aware that Enterprise distributed apps are signed with a special distribution certificate and provisioning profile which only allow the app to run after the device had an opportunity to check with apples servers if your certificate is still valid. This means that Apple, should they happen to learn about illicitly distributed Enterprise apps, is perfectly able to shut these apps down by revoking the distribution certificate. Furthermore, those certificates expire each year anyway just like the regular distribution certificates do.

Unfortunately, there's no real solution to your problem - I happen to know, because the 100 device limit put a halt to a research project of one of my clients, too. In their current form, the available development programs as offered by Apple offer only a minimum of flexibility. You might want to contact them about it, if enough people do, maybe they'll change something one day.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does distribution certificate expire each year ? If yes, how organization users can use the app (deployed from enterprise program) ?

Comment: You need to build your app again with your renewed distribution certificate and provisioning profile before the old one expires. Then just distribute the new version to your users. You need to do this at least once per year and I'd recommend to include an update reminder in your app so your users are made aware of the need to update.

Comment: OK, but if the year is spent, and users don't update with new app generated with new certificate, these users still can use the old app ?

Comment: No they can't. The app will stop working unless you provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple Enterprise Program will only allow distributing within the organization. Further Apple restricts the Enterprise Program to large organizations and there are other restrictions as to membership.

If you are looking for general distribution the Apple Enterprise Program is not an option.